# Failure while installing dependencies for odoo

Tags: python, ubuntu, odoo

So Im studying an odoo course in udemy. But I cant install the dependencies.
Im using ubuntu 20.04

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install python-cups python-dateutil python-decorator python-docutils python-feedparser
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-cups
E: Unable to locate package python-feedparser
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Have to download the correct dependencies for odoo based on your ubuntu version.
Dependencies for ubuntu 20.04 are here:
https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-install-odoo-on-ubuntu-20-04-18-04/

Answer (score 0):

Try running following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-cups python-dateutil python-decorator python-docutils python-feedparser
```